# Concurrent threads and shared object deadlocks

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I found out that this problem was very simple and that I did not even need help. Just took a while.

Comment: Since Model.tasks and Model.taskIndex are always decremented/incremented together, either one could be computed as a function of the other.  The advantage to that is that you could then use an `AtomicInteger` instead of a `synchronized` block to do the increment/decrement.  It won't make any significant performance difference if you're only doing it a hundred times, but it's still a good habit to get into.

Comment: The instance variable, Model.value, appears to serve no purpose.  Why not use a local variable in Model.getTask() instead?

Answer (score 0):

The `synchronized` keyword on a method locks the whole object, and not the small section of code you want.  What that means is that `nextTask` and `getTask` cause each other to block.

It might be better to use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` or stack internally.  Also, was it your intention to skip the first element of the array?  Array indexes start at 0.

Comment: I do not use an array. I simply use private fields and synchronized methods to do everything. When the first thread gets the first value to process, it calls getTask() which gives  it the value of 1 as this is the starting value. The index is then incremented to be 2 so that once the lock is released, the second thread will get 2 from getTask() and then change index to 3.

Comment: nextTask() is not being used. You will notice that it has been combined into getTask();

Comment: nextTask() and getTask() are trivial.  So what if they cause each other to block?  The amount of time that will be spent in either routine will be sub-microsecond.

Comment: @user2355058, When you're asking for help, it's polite to post the smallest example that demonstrates your problem.  Including methods that are not called is pretty far from polite.